# Condition in with and whereHas laravel has been duplicate

Tags: laravel

I have two table

```
1. news_categories
+----+---------------------+
| id |     created_at      |
+----+---------------------+
|  1 | 2020-10-10 10:10:10 |
+----+---------------------+
2. news_category_translations
+----+--------+---------------+---------+
| id | map_id | language_code |  name   |
+----+--------+---------------+---------+
|  1 |      1 | vi            | name vi |
|  2 |      1 | en            | name en |
+----+--------+---------------+---------+
```

How do I fix the looping condition in this code

```
$locale = \App::getLocale()
$category = \App\Models\NewsCategory::with(['translation' => function($q){
            $q->where('language_code', 'en'); // duplicate (1)
        }])->whereHas('translation', function($q){
            $q->where('language_code', 'en'); // duplicate (2)
        })->find(1);
```

Model NewCategory

```
public function translation()
{
    return $this->hasOne('App\Models\NewsCategoryTranslation', 'map_id', 'id');
}
```

I don't want to push conditional on the model.
**Update 1:**
When i remove condition (1) output:
`newsCategory  ['id' => 1, 'translation' => ['id' => 1]]` false because language_code = en
When i remove condition (2) and delete translation with id = 2 ouput:
`newsCategory ['id' => 1, 'translation' => null]` => false because record with language_code = en does not exist
When I use both conditions, the result is as expected. Why?
Sorry my english is quite bad and i don't have much experience with laravel. Thanks.
**Update 2:**
I have referenced the following article
`https://medium.com/@amritms/combining-wherehas-and-with-in-laravel-eloquent-c91391bd3c02`
And i see author use

```
$callback = function($query) {
    $query->where('something', '=', 'something');
}
$submissions = Post::whereHas('submissions', $callback)->with(['submissions' => $callback])->get();
```

If don't use it callback function it will be the same for me, duplicate condition from with and whereHas.

Comment: You might not need the condition inside the `with()` method.

Comment: I have tried but am missing the condition on my second mysql statement
```
select * from news_categories where exists (select * from news_category_translations where news_categories.id = news_category_translations.map_id and language_code = 'en') and news_categories.id = 1 limit 1
```
```
select * from news_category_translations where news_category_translations.map_id in (1)
```

Comment: From your relation, it seems that your `NewCategory` model has one `NewsCategoryTranslation`. So you won't need the condition on second query.

Comment: Remove condition 1, which is inside the `with()` method. Try this, `$category = NewsCategory::with(['translation'])->whereHas('translation', function($q){$q->where('language_code', 'en');})->find(1)`;

Comment: `NewsCategory::whereHas('translation', function($q){$q->where('language_code', 'en');})` will return `NewsCategory` which has a `language_code`  = 'en` translation. As the `translation` relation is **one to one** there will be only `NewsCategoryTranslation` whose  `language_code`  = 'en`.

Comment: I found the 2nd mysql statement to be missing the language condition
select * from news_category_translations where news_category_translations.map_id in (1)

Comment: Yes the second sql query won't have the condition. As you have filtering the first one with the relationship existence and the relation is **one to one** logically you don't need that condition in second query.

Comment: Am i building the wrong relationship ?. news_categories and news_category_translations relation: 1 - n

Comment: why do you need the `whereHas` since you are filtering out the result set by 'id'?

Comment: I have updated my question.

Comment: As per your updated question, I think you need `hasMany()` relation on `translation()` method.

Comment: Since the db structure has a `hasMany` relation, In my opinion you would need the condition in both queries.

Comment: Ok thank you very much.